# É possível manipular um ID no CSS através de outro ID?

Tags: css

Gostaria que, ao passar o mouse sobre a imagem `#imagem:hover` o `body` ficasse escuro, afim de focar só a imagem `#body: opacity: 0.5`

```css
.card-img-top:hover {
 border: 1px solid #007BFF;
 /* zoom ao passar o mouse */
 -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
 -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
 -o-transform: scale(1.1);
 -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
 transform: scale(1.1); 
}
```

```html
<img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100" >
```

Comment: Não é possível fazer apenas com *CSS*. É necessário *JavaScript*.

Comment: Entendi, obrigado pela resposta Valdeir!

Comment: Da pra fazer so com CSS, edita sua pergunta e coloca o que vc já tem de código, ai da pra gente votar para reabrir a questão

Comment: hugo coloquei o html e css, mas nao é muito coisa, coloquei só o básico pra entender como funciona mesmo, obrigado.

Comment: Weslley eu fiz uma edição e coloquei uma imagem para você ficar melhor se houver alguma resposta ...

Answer (score 0):

Exite um workar*o*und que vc pode fazer, ele funciona usando `box-shadow` bem grande, mas grande mesmo, tipo 3000px :)

Então quando vc fizer o `:hover` no elemento que for vc coloca o `box-shadow` e aumenta o `z-index` do elemento, só para garantir que ele vai ficar por sima dos outros e a sombra vai cobrir tudo.

Os 3000px vc tem que usar como o quarto valor do box-shadow, tipo 0 0 0 3000

```css
html,
body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    text-align: center;
}

.card-img-top {
    position: relative;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}

.card-img-top:hover {
    z-index: 1000;
    box-shadow: 0 0 0 3000px rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border: 1px solid #007BFF;
    /* zoom ao passar o mouse */
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
    -o-transform: scale(1.1);
    -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
    transform: scale(1.1);
}
```

```html
<img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100">
<p>
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit. Sunt quod necessitatibus ex maxime saepe officiis excepturi voluptates. Sapiente unde debitis, odit magnam suscipit iure voluptates eos animi nemo, beatae quae minima voluptatem sunt saepe consectetur nostrum! Ullam, consequuntur repellendus aspernatur quae cupiditate id voluptatem, nesciunt rerum voluptatibus tempora animi corporis quaerat ducimus, quibusdam reiciendis ratione. Provident temporibus earum corrupti, suscipit sit quis consequuntur aspernatur non delectus officia consectetur pariatur ullam error reprehenderit doloribus, sapiente magnam hic vel qui. Labore sit at architecto recusandae perferendis. Ea, </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiz um configuração inicial para um elemento `<p>` onde o mesmo vai cobrir toda a área da página e ao passar o mouse na imagem o elemento `<p>` vai alterar a cor e assim dando o efeito de escurecer mais do que a imagem, exemplo:

```css
.p {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: -1;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  left: 0;
  transition: .25s;
  pointer-events: none;
  background: #FFF;
}

.card-img-top:hover {
  border: 1px solid #007BFF;
  -webkit-transform: scale(1.1);
  -moz-transform: scale(1.1);
  -o-transform: scale(1.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1.1);
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.card-img-top:hover ~ .p {
  opacity: 0.5;
  background: #111;
  filter: alpha(opacity=50);
  -ms-filter:"progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Alpha(Opacity=50)";
}
```

```html
<div>
  <h1>Titulo da foto</h1>
  <img class="card-img-top" src="https://via.placeholder.com/140x100" border="0"> 
   <div class="p"></div>
</div>
<div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse eu leo a enim scelerisque rhoncus eget sit amet ipsum. Ut vel lacus quam. Ut pretium quam sit amet magna commodo, sit amet pharetra ex varius. Integer condimentum nisl ut aliquet suscipit. Praesent lacinia quam eget gravida dapibus. Nunc ullamcorper et nulla non ornare. Sed cursus diam neque, at fringilla risus volutpat non. Sed eget mauris blandit, consequat magna non, porttitor turpis. Quisque scelerisque urna odio, sit amet fermentum velit pretium at. Aenean maximus urna lacinia mauris bibendum, a fermentum ante iaculis. Donec augue nulla, pellentesque vitae efficitur efficitur, rutrum a justo. Nulla efficitur libero egestas, malesuada odio at, suscipit risus. Fusce elementum accumsan diam, eget vulputate nisi ornare et. Curabitur convallis ligula in hendrerit varius.

Aenean ut nisl pulvinar, pharetra neque at, varius libero. Vestibulum felis dui, posuere vitae dolor quis, venenatis rutrum tortor. Duis vestibulum diam sit amet ultricies lobortis. Praesent vulputate interdum scelerisque. Sed ornare mi eu vulputate convallis. Vivamus bibendum ullamcorper felis a finibus. Donec elementum libero nec orci eleifend, vel ultrices odio sagittis. Vivamus scelerisque tincidunt pharetra. Morbi porttitor ultrices nisi vel ultricies. Praesent venenatis rutrum odio, ut luctus urna congue ac. Curabitur maximus felis nec nibh interdum egestas. Praesent in velit pretium, imperdiet nunc nec, efficitur est. Integer placerat nibh felis, vel scelerisque mauris lobortis quis. In eget laoreet sapien. Praesent imperdiet rhoncus mauris, et rhoncus ligula porta gravida. Vivamus fermentum tempor justo, at dictum lectus fermentum ut.

Quisque risus arcu, feugiat eget sapien id, tincidunt accumsan neque. Quisque faucibus egestas felis vitae sollicitudin. Vivamus dictum rutrum vestibulum. Vestibulum ac sodales metus. Integer et interdum augue, ut molestie odio. Nullam nec sapien in eros egestas consectetur non at mauris. Morbi congue bibendum efficitur. Proin rhoncus velit id nulla tincidunt, vitae gravida lacus ultricies. Nullam lectus ipsum, consectetur vel odio sit amet, pulvinar pulvinar mauris.

Nullam urna augue, lobortis sit amet purus nec, tincidunt scelerisque nisl. Quisque ornare, eros ut cursus maximus, sapien felis rhoncus leo, in pulvinar augue velit ut nunc. Nulla sit amet augue porta, malesuada ipsum vitae, tincidunt lorem. In hac habitasse platea dictumst. Aenean non fringilla arcu. Praesent nec commodo nunc. Donec bibendum metus libero, ac tincidunt lorem vulputate aliquam. Ut non rhoncus erat. Vivamus at risus arcu. Sed erat nisi, viverra quis nisi nec, auctor vulputate ipsum.

Sed fringilla blandit congue. Curabitur aliquam, odio nec fermentum faucibus, nisl orci egestas nibh, sit amet mattis arcu magna tempus dolor. Donec pulvinar placerat est, nec condimentum felis imperdiet quis. Nunc vel fermentum ipsum, sit amet tempus dui. Nulla vel magna tellus. Nunc placerat mauris justo. Cras et magna condimentum, mollis diam et, suscipit elit. Vestibulum mattis, risus id aliquet mattis, metus diam vehicula leo, in pulvinar tellus eros at neque. Nulla id tincidunt mi. Nunc vehicula nisi leo, in consequat lacus finibus vitae. Aliquam ut justo placerat, venenatis dui vel, suscipit lectus. Duis id urna porttitor, ullamcorper odio at, sodales nulla. Nam urna elit, molestie vel orci ut, congue laoreet odio.</div>
```